# How to print Double-Quotes in Elisp

Tags: elisp

I can't seem to be able to insert the xml declaration in my code.

`(insert "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>")`

It's an easy question but I can't figure it out!

Comment: This wasn't really a good question! I know.. I couldn't remove it cause it has already answer in it.. Sorry StackOverflow Guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 (insert "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\" ?>")
```

This should work

Comment: I know that this was really a stupid question.. Anyways, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-for-Strings.html

> *To include a double-quote in a string, precede it with a backslash; thus, "\"" is a string containing just a single double-quote
>   character.*